# Set the height of the cell according to the height of the text content

Tags: ios, fonts, height, uitableview

I have a table containing dynamic cell. In each cell, I have textLabel and detailTextLabel. I would like to set the cell height equal to the sum of the height of the textLabel and detailTextLabel.This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

cell.textLabel.text=text;

cell.detailTextLabel.text=detailText;


return cell;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using `autolayout` or not?

Comment: yes,i use autolayout

Comment: @NimitParekh Who doesn't use Auto Layout anymore?

Comment: @Dan It's depends on the developer but of cause Auto Layout  is best.

Comment: @GianlucaCarpi see link http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using AutoLayout on iOS8, a important part is to tell the UITableView to be "autolayouted":

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0; // your estimated average cell height
```

Also, it would be best to use a custom cell and override the Method "layoutSubviews":

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Make sure the contentView does a layout pass here so that its subviews have their frames set, which we
    // need to use to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth below.
    [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];


    self.details.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.details.frame);
}
```

Checkout this [Example Project](https://github.com/itinance/UITableViewAutoHeight) at github.

Comment: please check out my updated answer and the example project: https://github.com/itinance/UITableViewAutoHeight :)

Comment: Bingo, this is it!!! I had been searching for a solution and tried so many things. This is not only simple but works.
My table is pretty complex with custom cells etc.
What worked for me was 
1)  add lines
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0; // your estimated average cell height

2) in the custom cell set the label
  label.numberOfLines = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Following code for Dynamic height of the UILabel.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath{
          if ( [detailText length] <= 0 ){
            CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(450, 40000.0f);
            CGSize size = [detailText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
            size.height = MAX(size.height,36);

            return 50+size.height;
        }
    return 150;
}
```

May this help to solve your problem.

Comment: What is it aMessage ?

Comment: it's your `NSString` Value.

Comment: I have this errore "Expected expression" in this string of code CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(450, 40000.0f);  Why?